# Typescript Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

[image]I am getting an error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'`and 'return void 0' error on console when i compile on ci pipeline.
Can anyone tell what's wrong in the code and how do i resolve these errors

```js
export function wait(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

export async function mapAsync<TIn, TOut>(
  items: TIn[],
  mapper: (item: TIn, index?: number) => Promise<TOut>,
): Promise<TOut[]> {
  const results: TOut[] = []

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i]
    const result = await mapper(item, i)
    results.push(result)
  }

  return results
}

export async function findAsync<T>(items: T[], predicate: (item: T, index?: number) => Promise<boolean>): Promise<T> {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i]
    const matches = await predicate(item, i)

    if (matches) {
      return item
    }
  }

  return void 0
}
```

Thank you

Comment: how is `findAsync` called? it looks like the generic being passed to it might be undefined.

Comment: @jmunsch it's the opposite: the inferred `T` is **not** `undefined`.

Comment: "what's wrong" --- yes, you declared `findAsync` to return a `Promise<T>` while you're returning a `Promise.resolve(undefined)`, and `undefined` is not assignable to `T` (which is unknown at this point, since you did not provide details on how you invoke that function).

Comment: @jmunsch I haven't called the function anywhere but in ci compiling  it gives a linting  error i guess

Comment: Either remove the return type annotation (it is optional) or write it properly, `Promise<T | undefined>`. Hint: look at the signature of `Array.prototype.find` it's built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement `return void 0` should be a promise to match the expected return type `Promise<T>`. Even if you did not run the function. The TS compiler will generate an error.

```
export function findAsync<T>(items: T[], predicate: (item: T, index?: number) => Promise<boolean>): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise<T>(async (resolve) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i]
        const matches = await predicate(item, i)

        if (matches) {
          resolve(item)
        }
      }

      resolve(0)
  });
}
```

Comment: That's correct but you have extra wrappers. Outer function is async but doesn't await

Comment: @AluanHaddad Correct. It was not going to generate any errors, but it has no use as well.